# count column in SQL and obtain condition

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

I have a table with name `test` in Oracle, and `(sal(integer),gender)` are the two columns in it.
I want to get counter number where gender is male, sal betwwen 1000,3000.

For example:  If I have three people in table test (two male ,one  female) and person1 sal =1000, person2 sal = 2020, person3 sal = 1040

The return value of sql statement will be equals (2).

The variable will store return value from java.

Comment: variable witch store count of person male and sal values from(1000,3000)

Comment: there's no function `sal` in oracle

Comment: sal is column name , can u tell me how to store value of condition that i wrote in question ..

Answer (score 0):

you actually want to count rows not column, as per what i understood from ur question. then you can use `count(column_name)` function of SQL along with the conditions (where clause).

Query: `SELECT COUNT(*) "Count" FROM test WHERE gender='male' AND salary BETWEEN 1000 AND 3000`

Comment: in this table person1, person2 = male 
person3 =female

Comment: thanks sooo much , but i wont to store it in java  variable .

Comment: as similar to how you query any other SELECT statement, it will return a resulset. whose result will contain only 1 row and 1 column, from which you can call getInt(0), and store it in a variable.

Comment: sire , why getInt(0) , whats (0) ?

Comment: do u think require while(rs.next()) ?

Comment: getInt(int index), it takes the index of columns in result-set. as there would be only 1 column, the 0th index would be that column.

Comment: please see my code 
int i=0;
resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(gender) FROM test WHERE gender= 'Male' AND sal  BETWEEN '111' AND '200'");
while (resultset.next())
{i++}
i = resultset.getInt(0);

Comment: to keep it simple, being just 1 row, you can actually skip while :::-

resultset = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(gender) FROM test WHERE gender= 'Male' AND sal = '111' "); 

resultset.next();
int i = resultset.getInt(0);

Comment: yesss,  i understood  , u say that if i have more row then can i while . right ?

Answer (score 0):

try this query,

```
select count(*) from <table_name> where gender='male' and salary between 1000 to 3000;
```

Comment: thank u , i know . but return value store in variable java !!?  can u help

Comment: yes, you need to store it in java variable only. You can use java.sql.ResultSet and iterate on it using resultSet.next() and you can access those values in java code